# Can I use Qt visual studio tools for comercial projects?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, dynamic-linking

I understand that I can work on closed source projects using Qt as long as I link dynamically the Qt libraries and don't include them in the release version of my app.

My question is, if I use Qt visual studio tools, would it compile it including the Qt libraries on my release? if so, how could I make use of Qt libraries in visual studio?

Also I guess another question would be, if I use the Qt IDE's like Qt Design studio can I compile my app so that it links the Qt framework dynamically?

Comment: I wouldn't trust any legal advice from random people on the internet. Why not instead ask Qt if they are going to sue you? Would probably be more reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This dialog in the installer has the answers to all your questions. So, with these limitations in this wizard, you can use the open source version of Qt in your project.

[image]

And yes, you can of course link against Qt dynamically either in qmake or cmake.

All these common and popular IDEs support cmake, like Visual Studio or QtCreator, so you should not worry about using Qt in these IDEs.

Comment: But in the case of Qt dynamically linking I would be able to not release my software as Open Source correct? my software would not be bound to the LGPL License correct?

Comment: As you can see in the answer, your software does not have to be LGPL.